# App shows "support wallet" in App store even though wallet is turned off in capabilities

Tags: ios, app-store, entitlements, passkit, wallet

We recently launched iOS app on the app store. Some of code files reference Passkit framework. Also Entitlements has been added with

```
com.apple.developer.pass-type-identifiers
```

key and respective team id. But inside app capabilities we have disabled Wallet. But still in app description in app store under support it shows Wallet. Has anyone faced same problem? Does anyone have clue on why it is shown? Is it because of the entitlement we have added or because of referencing Passkit.

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue in our app, have you determined why this is happening?

Comment: We've found out that the Urban Airship-Library links the Passbook-Framework. Apps that link against the Passbook-Framework are marked with the "support wallet"-badge.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, tipsi-stripe, which enables Stripe UI in React Native, depends on PassKit and it is marked as "required".

[image: tipsi-stripe]